# How can I replace in unix 'testxy\,' to testxy$

Tags: unix

I have tried writing:

```
newline='testxy\,'
templine1=`echo "$newline"|sed -e 's/\,/$/g'`
```

But i am getting result as `'testxy\$'`
How can i replace in unix `'testxy\,'` to `testxy&`

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) And the perfect question And how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) SO is not a free Coding or Code Conversion or Debugging or Tutorial or Library Finding service Here at SO we fix your attempts, we do not code things for you

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
templine1=$(echo "$newline" | sed -e 's/\\,/$/g')
```

Comment: Rolled back, @Jens.

Answer (score 0):

This is a working example:

```
newline='testxy\,'
templine1=$(echo "$newline"|sed -e 's/\\/$/g')
```

Basically, backslash needs to be escaped in `sed` by backslash to do what you want.